# Unable to resolve target 'android-19'

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to work with Android API 19. I changed inside project.properties file **target=android-19**. In AndroidManifest.xml. I have this :

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

But in project properties I have this : 
[image]

How can I change API level to 19 there to get rid of the error in the title.
Thanks.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

1. Go to Windows -> Android SDK Manager
   Install the Android API Level you want, in this case 19.
2. Once you've finished installing, go to Window -> Preference -> Android.
   You should get a list of available targets. Click 'Apply' then 'Ok'.
3. Now right click your project, go to properties. Click Android. Choose your desired target.

Comment: I was struggling with windows 8.1 because I was not starting SDK manager as administrator. Make sure that you start it as admin or you'll get bunch of errors as I did!

Answer (score 3):

1. Right click on your project
2. Go to properties  -> Click Android (Left pane)
3. Select Your project target version.
4. Restart the Eclipse
5. Clean the project (click Project menu-> clean)
6. Now run the project.

Answer (score 2):

Window -> Preference -> Android. You should get a list of available targets. Click 'Apply' then 'Ok'.

Now right click your project, go to properties. Click Android. Choose your desired target.

Answer (score 0):

Window->Preferences->Android and validate your sdk location after that open your Android SDK Manager and validate if you have installed API 19

Comment: I have SDK19.. How can I try with that?

Comment: @user306587 your answer is unclear. Please, be a bit more descriptive and provide more information for your solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check and add your SDK API20 to project, clean and build project.

You can ignore this warning

EDIT:

If you can work with 19 you must install API 19 through Android SDK