# My SDK Manager recognizes the SDK but Eclipse doesn't when debugging

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, android-sdk-manager

As the title says, i tried to use Eclipse for android programming.I installed ADT plugin and set SDK directory.When i open SDK Manager in eclipse it recognizes and shows every SDK version that i'm expecting, but as it appears the IDE doesn't recognize the SDKs and i see this error in console:

Unable to resolve target 'android-19'

I even tried to set SDK target version in my project's "Properties". But there, in the "Android" window's "Project Bundle Target" box, i have only API 23 Option(that was default in the Eclipse's version that i installed).

Now what is the problem and why i get that error and all API 19 classes can't be found in repository even though the SDK Manager recognize the SDK ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But did you actually download API 19 through SDK Manager? When you extract Android 4.4.2 (API 19) in SDK Manager tree does it said Status Installed? If not then go to the android-sdk folder and run SDK manager.exe as administrator and download API 19 first. Then you should be able to set it as default in project properties in eclipse.

And you should also check this thread:

[Unable to resolve target 'android-19'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25025233/unable-to-resolve-target-android-19)

Comment: Actually i just set the SDKs' path to the SDKs that i used in Android Studio; But the SDK Manager's status was showing that it's "installed". Though, i decided to re-install Eclipse and this time i got the API through SDK Manager as you said and the rest(besides installing some necessary extensions, etc.) goes as the thread you mentioned points.

Thank you for your help